# Can we rename the main.swift file to Main.swift (uppercased)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, camelcasing

In Xcode for the Command line tool, can we rename the `main.swift` file to `Main.swift` (uppercased), supposedly to respect the PascalCase nomenclature?! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Use `@main` attribute.

> @main. Apply this attribute to a structure, class, or enumeration declaration to indicate that it contains the top-level entry point for program flow. The type must provide a main type function that doesn’t take any arguments and returns Void.
> For example:

```
@main
struct MyTopLevel {
    static func main() {
        // Top-level code goes here
    }
}
```

[Swift docs on attributes.](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html)